# How to select two files from a directory, and always every other file?

Tags: bash, directory

I am currently working on RNA-Seq data, and I have a directory containing the forward and the reverse sequences of a number of samples. I want to run tools such as SortMeRNA, but to do this I need the file names of both the forward and the reverse sequence as the data is pair-ended.

My directory looks akin to like this:

```
data/expression/samples/K1-01_sortmerna_trimmomatic_1.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-01_sortmerna_trimmomatic_2.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-02_sortmerna_trimmomatic_1.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-02_sortmerna_trimmomatic_2.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-03_sortmerna_trimmomatic_1.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-03_sortmerna_trimmomatic_2.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-04_sortmerna_trimmomatic_1.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-04_sortmerna_trimmomatic_2.fq.gz
...
data/expression/samples/K1-20_sortmerna_trimmomatic_1.fq.gz
data/expression/samples/K1-20_sortmerna_trimmomatic_2.fq.gz
```

What I want to do is to select the files in pairs and assign them to a variable that I can then pass on to the selected software without having to make a variable for each file.

I want the code to work by giving me `$FWD` and `$REV` as the file names `K1-01_sortmerna_trimmomatic_1.fq.gz` and `K1-01_sortmerna_trimmomatic_2.fq.gz`.

The next time it iterates over the directory to give `$FWD` and `$REV` as `K1-02_sortmerna_trimmomatic_1.fq.gz` and `K1-02_sortmerna_trimmomatic_2.fq.gz` respectively.

I have made this code, which is probably not a very efficient way of dealing with this problem (and that do not work).

```sh
DATA_LOCATION=data/expression/samples/
cd $DATA_LOCATION
files=(*.fq.gz)
total=${#files[@]}
idx=0

FWD_DONE=false
REV_DONE=false

for file in "${files[@]:idx}"; do

    if [ !$FWD_DONE ]; then
        idx=$(( idx + 1 ))
        FWD=$(basename $file)[$idx]
        echo $FWD
        FWD_DONE=true
        REV_DONE=false
    fi

    if [ !$REV_DONE ] && [ $FWD_DONE ]; then
        idx=$(( idx + 1 ))
        REV=$(basename $file)[$idx]
        echo $REV
        REV_DONE=true
        FWD_DONE=false
    fi

    echo index $idx
done
```

Unfortunately, this makes the `$FWD` and `$REV` variables the same for each pass. My guess is that it has something to do with the `for` statement not updating with the index increment inside. Unfortunately I am very new to shell scripting, and I have yet to find any other sources that has any help.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I am more than willing to trash my own code if it means that the whole process can become simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `cd`ed to the directory containing the data files, does this code do what you want?

```
for fwd in *_1.fq.gz; do
    rev=${fwd%_1.fq.gz}_2.fq.gz
    # CODE THAT USES "$fwd" AND "$rev" GOES HERE
done
```

- See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why I replaced `FWD` and `REV` with `fwd` and `rev`.

Comment: It does indeed do what I want! Thank you!